# I want to replace a whole line in php

Tags: php, design-patterns

I would like to replace

```
'HASH_KEY' => string '1234567890123' (length=13)
```

by

```
'HASH_KEY' => hide
```

But I can't get it. I tried this:

```
'SESSION_TIME' => int 10
'HASH_KEY' => string '1234567890123' (length=13)
'DB_HOST' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
'DB_USER' => string 'user' (length=4)
'DB_PASS' => string 'pass' (length=4)

preg_replace("/\'HASH_KEY\'[a-zA-Z0-9\=\>\'\ ]*$/", 'HASH_KEY => hide', $string);
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Are you assigning the result back to `$string`?

Comment: `$` needs the `/m` multiline flag there. Also why aren't you just stripping the entry before the var_dump or whatever?

Comment: You don't have parentheses in your regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to process the function result somehow, f.e. assign it to a variable.
Use the `.` for an (almost) `any character wildcard` and the `*` to define that it should occure `0..n` times. Attach the multiline flag `m` at the end.

```
$output = preg_replace("/'HASH_KEY'.*=\>.*$/m", "'HASH_KEY' => hide", $string);
```

Please try the full script:

```
<?php

$string = "
'SESSION_TIME' => int 10
'HASH_KEY' => string '1234567890123' (length=13)
'DB_HOST' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
'DB_USER' => string 'user' (length=4)
'DB_PASS' => string 'pass' (length=4)
";

$output = preg_replace("/'HASH_KEY'.*=\>.*$/m", "'HASH_KEY' => hide", $string);

echo "<pre>" . $output . "</pre>"; 

?>
```

Comment: I was assigning the result into a variable. That doesn't work

Comment: I wrote preg_replace("/'HASH_KEY'.*$/m", "'HASH_KEY' => hide", $string) and it works, thanks so much